# Dynamics CRM Web Service Execute returns "Server was unable to process request."

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm going crazy here with DCRM web services,

I'm trying to create a Connection between two leads dynamically.
I'm getting the following error:

```
"0x80040216
  An unexpected error occurred.
  Platform
  An unexpected error occurred.

Type:Microsoft.Crm.CrmException ErrorCode:0x80040216
Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

Here is my code:

```
Guid connectionRoleID = new Guid("64f33a74-0342-e211-b55e-00155d00041e");
connectionroleobjecttypecode connroleobjecttypecode = new connectionroleobjecttypecode() { connectionroleid = new Lookup(){Value = connectionRoleID}, associatedobjecttypecode = EntityName.lead.ToString()};

connection conn = new connection();
List<Property> list = new List<Property>();

Lookup lookup = new Lookup();
lookup.Value = customers[i].ID.Value.Value;
lookup.name = EntityName.lead.ToString();

Lookup lookup2 = new Lookup();
lookup2.Value = customers[j].ID.Value.Value;
lookup2.name = EntityName.lead.ToString();

conn.record1roleid = new Lookup() { name = "duplicate", Value = new Guid("64f33a74-0342-e211-b55e-00155d00041e") };
conn.record2roleid = new Lookup() { name = "duplicate", Value = new Guid("64f33a74-0342-e211-b55e-00155d00041e") };
list.Add(new LookupProperty(){Name = "record1id", Value = lookup});
list.Add(new LookupProperty(){Name = "record2id", Value = lookup2});
list.Add(new LookupProperty(){Name = "record1roleid", Value = conn.record1roleid});
list.Add(new LookupProperty() { Name = "record2roleid", Value = conn.record2roleid });
```

I've tried tracing (which did not help), and in the eventviewer I get an error, but there is no helpful information.

I'm dying here! Please help... :-)

Comment: This fragment is not enough information. How did you find that exception occur here? Also I'm very curious what this type represents: connectionroleobjecttypecode

Comment: Is this definetly a CRM 4 question? Connections are a 2011 feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are doing:

```
conn.record1roleid = new Lookup() { name = "duplicate", Value = new Guid("64f33a74-0342-e211-b55e-00155d00041e") };
```

`name` should be the name of an entity, e.g. contact, lead, incident. In this case I believe you should be using: connectionrole.

```
conn.record1roleid = new Lookup() { name = "connectionrole", Value = new Guid("64f33a74-0342-e211-b55e-00155d00041e") };
```

I would suggest having at [Sample: Create a Connection (Early Bound)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509054.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Add type for the entity to lookup

```
Lookup lookup2 = new Lookup();
lookup2.Value = customers[j].ID.Value.Value;
lookup2.name = EntityName.lead.ToString();
**lookup2.type = "lead";**
```